# How to modify a single value of a 2D tensor programatically by index

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing, tensor

I have a 2D tensor `my_tensor` size `[50,50]` and dtype `int32` and I need to increment the value at one specific location. The indices of the location to be updated is given by 2 integer tensors, which give the location in axis 0 and axis 1, respectively:

```
idx_0 is:
tf.Tensor([27], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
idx_1 is:
tf.Tensor([26], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

Tensorflow's tensor_scatter_nd_add seems to be the solution. The code works if I define the indexes manually, but if I try to use idx_0 and idx_1, every implementation gives some index/dimension mis-match error.

This works, incrementing location (27,26):

```
tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(reversals_count, [[27, 26]], [1])
```

but this raises an error:

```
tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(reversals_count, [[idx_0, idx_1]], [1])
```

with the error message

```
{InvalidArgumentError}Outer dimensions of indices and update must match. Indices shape: [1,2,1], updates shape:[1] [Op:TensorScatterAdd]
```

How can I use the `idx_0` and `idx_1` tensors in place of `[[27, 26]]`? Other syntaxes I've tried similarly do not produce the correct dimensions:

```
[[idx_0], [idx_1]]

tf.concat([idx_0, idx_1], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an (5x5) unit matrix for sake of simplicity and updating them at indices (0,0) ,(1,1),(2,2),(3,3) (i.e at the first four diagonal elements) . First define the indices as tensors ,then values as tensors that will add up those at respective indices then update using "tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add" command . You can do similarly for a (50X50) matrix.Thanks!

```
import tensorflow as tf
indices = tf.constant([[0,0], [1,1], [2,2],[3,3]]) # updating at diagonal index elements, you can see the change
updates = tf.constant([9, 10, 11, 12])# values that will add up at respective indexes
print("original tensor is ")
tensor = tf.ones([5,5], dtype=tf.int32)
print(tensor)
print("updated tensor is ")
updated = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor, indices, updates)
print(updated)
```